# HTML5 Canvas - Enemy Shooting

Tags: javascript, canvas, trigonometry

I'm making a game in HTML5 Canvas. Right now I'm trying to make it so the enemy (a ground to air gun) can shoot in the direction of the player (a plane).

My game uses 2 arrays to make a map according to the values in it. Because the game won't know how many enemies to put on the screen until it goes through the map, I have it create a new enemy with a random id, and have it add it to an object that keeps track of the enemies every time it comes across an enemy value in the map.

The problem comes when the enemies shoot at the plane, they all shoot at the same angle, and not at the angle necessary for that particular situation.

Here's the question: How can I get each enemy to shoot at the player at the correct angle?

I realize that this question/explanation may be a little confusing to understand, but please give it a shot. It would be good to start looking at lines 222-257 (The updateEntity function). (Please be aware that this is a separate code example from my real game code, it's not the best.)

Code on google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By026U5OT4C7OUZSNG5GM19kV1U

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k2xwypkp/

Whole code:

```
<center><canvas id = "gameCanvas" width = "500" height = "500" style = "border:1px solid navy;"></canvas></center>
var canvas, ctx;
var clip = {};
var arsenal = {};
var enemyClip = {};
var keyDown = {};
var enemy = {};
window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        createEnemy(Math.random(), i * 100 + 140);
    }
    setInterval(function() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        update();
    }, 1000 / 30);
}
var player = {
    x: 240,
    y: 240,
    w: 20,
    h: 20,
    color: "navy",
    alive: true,
    canShoot: true,
    canNuke: true,
    facingRight: true,
    draw: function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    },
    shoot: function() {
        if (player.canShoot) {
            player.canShoot = false;
            if (player.facingRight) {
                createPlayerBullet(Math.random(), player.x + player.w, player.y + player.h / 2, true);
            } else {
                createPlayerBullet(Math.random(), player.x, player.y + player.h / 2, false);
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                player.canShoot = true;
            }, 750);
        }
    },
    nuke: function() {
        if (player.canNuke) {
            player.canNuke = false;
            createNuke(Math.random(), player.x + player.w / 2, player.y + player.h);
            setTimeout(function() {
                player.canNuke = true;
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
}
//var enemy = {
//  x:240,
//  y:480,
//  w:20,
//  h:20,
//  color:"maroon",
//  alive:true,
//  canShoot:true,
//  
//  draw:function(){
//      ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
//      ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
//  },
//  
//  shoot:function(){
//      if(enemy.canShoot){
//          enemy.canShoot = false;
//      
//          if(player.x >= enemy.x && player.y <= enemy.y){// Top Right: TF, Bottom Right: TT, Bottom Left: FT, Top Left: FF
//              createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy.x + enemy.w/2, enemy.y, player.x, player.y, true, false); // True equals ___ is greater than
//          }else if(player.x >= enemy.x && player.y >= enemy.y){
//              createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy.x + enemy.w/2, enemy.y, player.x, player.y, true, true);
//          }else if(player.x <= enemy.x && player.y >= enemy.y){
//              createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy.x + enemy.w/2, enemy.y, player.x, player.y, false, true);
//          }else if(player.x <= enemy.x && player.y <= enemy.y){
//              createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy.x + enemy.w/2, enemy.y, player.x, player.y, false, false);
//          }
//          
//          setTimeout(function(){
//              enemy.canShoot = true;
//          }, 750);
//      }
//  }
//}
var createEnemy = function(ID, X) {
    var e = {
        x: X,
        y: 480,
        w: 20,
        h: 20,
        color: "maroon",
        alive: true,
        canShoot: true,
        id: ID,
        draw: function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        },
        shoot: function() {
            if (this.canShoot) {
                this.canShoot = false;
                if (player.x >= this.x && player.y <= this.y) { // Top Right: TF, Bottom Right: TT, Bottom Left: FT, Top Left: FF
                    createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), this.x + this.w / 2, this.y, player.x, player.y, true, false); // True means greater than
                } else if (player.x >= this.x && player.y >= this.y) {
                    createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), this.x + this.w / 2, this.y, player.x, player.y, true, true);
                } else if (player.x <= this.x && player.y >= this.y) {
                    createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), this.x + this.w / 2, this.y, player.x, player.y, false, true);
                } else if (player.x <= this.x && player.y <= this.y) {
                    createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), this.x + this.w / 2, this.y, player.x, player.y, false, false);
                }
                setTimeout(function() {
                    enemy.canShoot = true;
                }, 750);
            }
        }
    };
    enemy[e.id] = e;
}
var createPlayerBullet = function(ID, X, Y, dir) {
    var playerBullet = {
        x: X,
        y: Y,
        w: 5,
        h: 5,
        color: "navy",
        id: ID,
        facingRight: dir,
        draw: function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    }
    clip[playerBullet.id] = playerBullet;
}
var createEnemyBullet = function(ID, X, Y, playerx, playery, dirx, diry) {
    var enemyBullet = {
        x: X,
        y: Y,
        w: 5,
        h: 5,
        color: "maroon",
        id: ID,
        dirX: dirx,
        dirY: diry,
        playerX: playerx,
        playerY: playery,
        draw: function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    }
    enemyClip[enemyBullet.id] = enemyBullet;
}
var createNuke = function(ID, X, Y) {
    var nuke = {
        x: X,
        y: Y,
        w: 5,
        h: 5,
        color: "green",
        id: ID,
        draw: function() {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    }
    arsenal[nuke.id] = nuke;
}
var updateEntity = function() {
    for (var playerBullet in clip) {
        clip[playerBullet].draw();
        if (clip[playerBullet].facingRight) {
            clip[playerBullet].x += 8;
        } else {
            clip[playerBullet].x -= 8;
        }
        if (clip[playerBullet].x <= 0) {
            delete clip[playerBullet];
        } else if (clip[playerBullet].x >= canvas.width) {
            delete clip[playerBullet];
        }
    }
    for (var nuke in arsenal) {
        arsenal[nuke].draw();
        arsenal[nuke].y += 3;
        if (arsenal[nuke].y >= canvas.height) {
            delete arsenal[nuke];
        }
    }
    for (var enemyBullet in enemyClip) {
        for (var e in enemy) {
            var dx = enemy[e].x - enemyClip[enemyBullet].playerX;
            var dy = enemy[e].y - enemyClip[enemyBullet].playerY;
            var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        }
        enemyClip[enemyBullet].draw();
        if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirX && !enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirY) {
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].x -= 10 * Math.cos(angle);
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].y -= 10 * Math.sin(angle);
        } else if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirX && enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirY) {
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].x -= 10 * Math.cos(angle);
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].y -= 10 * Math.sin(angle);
        } else if (!enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirX && enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirY) {
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].x -= 10 * Math.cos(angle);
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].y -= 10 * Math.sin(angle);
        } else if (!enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirX && !enemyClip[enemyBullet].dirY) {
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].x -= 10 * Math.cos(angle);
            enemyClip[enemyBullet].y -= 10 * Math.sin(angle);
        }
        if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].x <= 0) {
            delete enemyClip[enemyBullet];
        } else if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].x >= canvas.width) {
            delete enemyClip[enemyBullet];
        } else if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].y <= 0) {
            delete enemyClip[enemyBullet];
        } else if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].y >= canvas.height) {
            delete enemyClip[enemyBullet];
        } else if (enemyClip[enemyBullet].x >= player.x && enemyClip[enemyBullet].x <= player.x + player.w && enemyClip[enemyBullet].y >= player.y && enemyClip[enemyBullet].y <= player.y + player.h) {
            delete enemyClip[enemyBullet];
        }
    }
}
var update = function() {
    updateEntity();
    if (player.alive) {
        player.draw();
    }
    //if(enemy.alive){
    //  enemy.draw();
    //  enemy.shoot();
    //}
    for (var e in enemy) {
        ctx.fillStyle = enemy[e].color;
        ctx.fillRect(enemy[e].x, enemy[e].y, enemy[e].w, enemy[e].h);
        if (enemy[e].canShoot) {
            enemy[e].canShoot = false;
            if (player.x >= enemy[e].x && player.y <= enemy[e].y) { // Top Right: TF, Bottom Right: TT, Bottom Left: FT, Top Left: FF
                createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy[e].x + enemy[e].w / 2, enemy[e].y, player.x, player.y, true, false); // True equals ___ is greater than
            } else if (player.x >= enemy[e].x && player.y >= enemy[e].y) {
                createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy[e].x + enemy[e].w / 2, enemy[e].y, player.x, player.y, true, true);
            } else if (player.x <= enemy[e].x && player.y >= enemy[e].y) {
                createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy[e].x + enemy[e].w / 2, enemy[e].y, player.x, player.y, false, true);
            } else if (player.x <= enemy[e].x && player.y <= enemy[e].y) {
                createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), enemy[e].x + enemy[e].w / 2, enemy[e].y, player.x, player.y, false, false);
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                for (var e in enemy) {
                    enemy[e].canShoot = true;
                }
            }, 750);
        }
    }
    if (37 in keyDown) {
        player.facingRight = false;
        player.x -= 5;
    }
    if (38 in keyDown) {
        player.y -= 5;
    }
    if (39 in keyDown) {
        player.facingRight = true;
        player.x += 5;
    }
    if (40 in keyDown) {
        player.y += 5;
    }
    if (32 in keyDown) {
        player.shoot();
    }
    if (90 in keyDown) {
        player.nuke();
    }
}
addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    keyDown[e.keyCode] = true;
});
addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    delete keyDown[e.keyCode];
});
```

I appreciate your time spent trying (and hopefully) helping me. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The problem with your question is it involves a lot of different pieces and that doesn't fit the format of this Q&A session. If you asked for how to programmatically calculate an angle and showed us what you tried, that's one thing, but your question is far more involved than that.

Answer (score 1):

This code in `updateEntity`

```
for (var enemyBullet in enemyClip) {
    for (var e in enemy) {
        var dx = enemy[e].x - enemyClip[enemyBullet].playerX;
        var dy = enemy[e].y - enemyClip[enemyBullet].playerY;
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
    }
```

Should be written without the for loop. You should just refer to the enemy that shot the bullet.

```
for (var enemyBullet in enemyClip) {
    var bullet = enemyClip[enemyBullet]; 
    var dx = bullet.enemyX - bullet.playerX;
    var dy = bullet.enemyY - bullet.playerY;
    var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
```

However, instead of storing all this information when a bullet is shot, you should just calculate the angle of the bullet when it is shot (it is not necessary for the bullet to know the player position and the 'dir' value seems unnecessary)

```
if (enemy[e].canShoot) {
  enemy[e].canShoot = false;
  var angle = Math.atan2( enemy[e].y-player.y, enemy[e].x-player.x);   
  ...      
  createEnemyBullet(Math.random(), angle, enemy[e].x + enemy[e].w/2, enemy[e].y);
```

Your `updateEntity` code then just becomes:

```
for (var enemyBullet in enemyClip) {
  var angle = enemyClip[enemyBullet].angle;
```

Before you go further I would suggest that you look at your code and review how you can simplify it there is a lot that could be removed. You create enemy bullets in 2 places and each place has 4 calls to `createEnemyBullet` also consider how enemy bullets and player bullets are the same. Also `Math.random()` is not a good way to generate a unique id. Just use an incrementing number each time (although there is no real reason for the id in this code)